# Short story about a primitive warrior in a microcosm

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story in the 80s. It was about a primitive hunter or warrior engaged in some primal struggle with a foe. He defeats his enemy and feels like he is master of his domain, only to have the perspective change to that of an observing scientist who is watching the microcosmic drama unfold from the other side of a dome...?

Comment: Was this a story from the pulp era? I have a vague recollection of a story like this from a *Before the Golden Age* type anthology.

Comment: There is a chess-themed story with some of these elements.  If you think it could be yours, I'll try to find it.

Comment: It was in an anthology I read in the 80s, but the book may have been printed years earlier, I don't recall if there was a chess theme or not, the whole story took place out of doors, as far as I can remember...

Answer (score 2):

This is a long shot, but certain aspects of the description are reminiscent of [Poul Anderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poul_Anderson)'s short story ["The Immortal Game"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58293), which might be the "chess-themed story" suggested in a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117012/cant-recall-title-or-author-of-short-story-i-read-as-a-child-about-primitive-wa#comment286005_117012) by Daphne B. First published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, February 1954](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61077) (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v006n02_1954-02/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v006n02_1954-02#page/n115/mode/2up)), it has appeared in a number of anthologies, including [*Run to Starlight, Sports Through Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?28617) (1976), [*Pawn to Infinity*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?25765) (1982), and [*Isaac Asimov's Magical Worlds of Fantasy #3: Cosmic Knights*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?178505) (1985).

The "microcosmic drama", described from the microcosmic perspective as a battle between two small medieval armies, is actually a game of chess played by computers:

> *"I see," nodded the visitor. "Individual computers, each controlling its own robot piece by a tight beam, and all the computers on a given side linked to form a sort of group-mind constrained to obey the rules of chess and make the best possible moves. Very nice. And it's a pretty cute notion of yours, making the robots look like medieval armies." His glance studied the tiny figures where they moved on the oversized board under one glaring floodlight.
>
>
> "Oh, that's pure frippery," said the scientist. "This is really a serious research project in multiple computer-linkages. By letting them play game after game, I'm getting some valuable data."*
>
> [. . . .]
>
> *"Hm." The visitor stooped over the board. "Notice how they're jumping around inside their squares, waving their arms, batting at each other with their weapons?" He paused, then murmured slowly: "I wonder—I wonder if your computers may not have consciousness. If they might not have—minds.
>
>
> "Don't get fantastic," snorted the scientist.*

Of course, this being a science fiction story, the computers *are* conscious. Most of the story is told from the viewpoint of the black king's bishop:

> The first trumpet sounded far and clear and brazen cold, and Rogard the Bishop stirred to wakefulness with it. Lifting his eyes, he looked through the suddenly rustling, murmuring line of soldiers, out across the broad plain of Cinnabar and the frontier, and over the the realm of LEUKAS.
>
> Away there, across the somehow unreal red-and-black distances of the steppe, he saw sunlight flash on armor and caught the remote wild flutter of lifted banners. *So it is war*, he thought. *So we must fight again.*

Adding to the implausibility, the author has the sentient chessmen reenact a famous historical game, the so-called [Immortal Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortal_Game), Anderssen–Kieseritzky 1851. They are hardly making the "best possible moves", especially Black, who gets checkmated on move 23:

> Slowly, very slowly, Flambard [the black king] looked around him. SORKAS, MERKON, THEUTAS, they were crouched to leap on him wherever he turned; his own men raged helpless against the Barriers; there was no place for him to go.
>
> He bowed his head. "I surrender," he whispered.
>
> Rogard looked across the red and black to Evyan [the black queen]. Their eyes met, and they stretched out their arms to each other.
>
> *"Checkmate," said the scientist. "That game's over."
>
>
> He crossed the room to the switchboard and turned off the computers.*

So we have medieval warriors fighting on a microcosmic battlefield, and at the end the perspective shifts to the observing scientists. That part matches. What doesn't match is that it's not single combat, but two small armies of 16 "men" on a side; and the viewpoint character is not the victorious white king but a bishop on the losing side; and there is no mention of a dome.